# How do I imitate Gmail's "Swipe to delete" in KendoUI ? Example included

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, user-interface, kendo-ui

I am trying to recreate Gmail (on Android's) "swipe to delete" interface. In this GUI the user can

- Swipe left or swipe right, and the entire list item moves with the thumb.
- After it is swiped more than X distance, the item swooshes away and is replaced with an "undo" icon
- Releasing the row, if X distance hasn't been reached, should put the object in its original place.
- If a second item is swiped, and an undo box is showing from a previous swipe, that row is deleted, and the animation and logic starts all over from scratch.

I have a demo of this working here, but it doesn't seem to perform too well.  http://jsbin.com/EWUbeTI/2/edit

Is there a more efficient way to handle this animation?

Comment: Using the Touch Swipe event like you are doing is the way I would usually accomplish this too. If you wanted to take it a step further and actually follow your finger, you would have to write some custom code to "drag" the element around and respond to the offset from where the drag started.

Answer (score 4):

This one is primarily about positioning and handling a lot of touch events.  There are two divs placed on top of one another.  Each is absolutely positioned to pull this off.

**Top Div (Email)**
When a drag occurs, the top div alters its left position by the drag delta IF that delta is negative (moving left) and the current left value of the row is not greater than 0 (prevents a right drag).  When the dragging stops, if the row has been moved at least 25% of the width of the container, we assume the user wants to commit and we go ahead and slide it all the way off.  Otherwise we set its left back to zero and then animate it back in as a canceled drag.

**Bottom Div (Archive)**
The bottom div doesn't move, but handles the touch of the area.  If the touch occurs on the button, the item is collapsed (you could slide as well).  A smooth collapsing requires you to remove the padding kendo ui mobile sets on the element.

http://jsbin.com/AfoQUKoQ/2/edit

**NOTE:** This implementation is very specific to the iOS 7 skin and wont work right with others due to the specific CSS styling

Hopefully this gets you moving in the right direction.